# Jquery headache - live traversing

Tags: jquery, live, traversal

I am trying to accomplish to show a div that is in the same list element as the button that executes a javascript statement.
The whole list is loaded by Ajax, so therefore is the live function used.

However, i am quite stuck right now and have no idea of how to proceed. I have tried EQ, next, parent, children in several different ways to succeed, but it have only given me even more headache.

```
$('a[rel*=button]')
    .live('click', function(event) { 
       event.preventDefault(); 
       url = this.href;
     $(this).next().find(".theclassofthediviwannashow").show();
      return false;
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="mydiv">
   <ul>
      <li class="mylist">
         <a href="#" rel="button">Linktext</a>
         <div class="theclassofthediviwannashow">Bla bla bla</div>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope that there is anyone who have an idea of what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `div` you want to show is always next use [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) but you say you have tried that. What you might be looking for is [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```
$('a[rel*=button]')
  .live('click', function(event) { 
      event.preventDefault(); 
      url = this.href;
      $(this).nextAll(".theclassofthediviwannashow").show();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

If your div always follows the link element, you should just be able to do:

```
$(this).next().show()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('a[rel*=button]')
    .live('click', function(event) { 
       event.preventDefault(); 
       url = this.href;
     $(this).next(".theclassofthediviwannashow").show();
      return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding your question, but just removing `.find(".theclassofthediviwannashow")` and leaving just `$(this).next().show();` seems to do what you want.